# Google Scripts to draft replies to emails with keyword in subject and inputting data from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail

I'm new to Google Apps Script so I'm looking for some advice. There's multiple parts and I managed to do some of it but I'm stuck on others. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to make a script that:

1. drafts a reply to emails that contain specific keywords (found in the body or the subject line).
2. I also want it to include a template with data inputted from a Google Sheets file.
3. It would be preferable if the draft can be updated without making a duplicate whenever the Sheet is modified.
4. I plan on also including a row of values (the first one) that correspond to the Subject columns in the second row the but I haven't gotten to it yet.

[image: Screenshot of a test Sheet]

Some details about the Google Sheet:

- Each row corresponds to a different person and email address that regularly emails me.
- The first three columns are details about the person which I include in the body of my draft.
- Each column after that represents a different string or keyword I expect to find in the subject of the emails sent to me.
- The rows underneath contain two patterned code-words separated by a space in one cell that I want to be able to choose from. Such as:

  - 3 letters that can contain permutations of the letters m, g, r (for ex: mmg, rgm, rgg, gmg)
  - and 0-3 letters with just p's (for ex: p, pp, ppp, or blank)

I want to be able to detect the different codes and assign it to a variable I can input into my draft.

---

What I have so far:

- I'm able to draft replies for emails within my specified filter. However, I only have it set up to reply to the person's most recent message. I want to be able for sort through the filter for specific emails that contain a keyword in the subject line when it loops through the columns.
- I'm able to input static strings from the Sheet into the body of my email but I'm still having trouble with the patterned codewords.
- I was able to loop through more than one row in earlier version but now it's not. I'll look over it again later.

Here's my code:

```
function draftEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();    // Use data from the active sheet
  var startRow = 1;                            // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;        // Number of rows to process
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();      // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn) // Fetch the data range of the active sheet
  var data = dataRange.getValues();            // Fetch values for each row in the range

  // Work through each row in the spreadsheet
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    // Assign each row a variable
    var grader = row[0];                    // Col A: Grader's name
    var firstName = row[1];                 // Col B: Student's first name
    var studentEmail = row[2];              // Col C: Student's email
    var grade = row[3].split(' ');           // Col D: Grade
    var pgrade = grade[1];
    var hgrade = grade[0];
      for (var n = 1; n < data.length; ++n) {
      var srow = data[n];  
      var subjectCol = srow[3];

    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('testLabel').getThreads();

    for (i=0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
          var thread = threads[i]; 
          var messages = thread.getMessages(); // get all messages in thread i
          var lastmsg  = messages.length - 1;  // get last message in thread i

          var emailTo    = WebSafe(messages[lastmsg].getTo());    // get only email id from To field of last message
          var emailFrom  = WebSafe(messages[lastmsg].getFrom());  // get only email id from FROM field of last message
          var emailCC    = WebSafe(messages[lastmsg].getCc());    // get only email id from CC field of last message


    // form a new CC header for draft email
        if (emailTo == "")
        {
           var emailCcHdr = emailCC.toString();
        } else
        {
          if (emailCC == "")
          {
            var emailCcHdr = emailTo.toString();
          } else
          {
            var emailCcHdr = emailTo.toString() + "," + emailCC.toString();
          }
        }

        var subject  = messages[lastmsg].getSubject().replace(/([\[\(] *)?(RE|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$/igm,"");
        // the above line remove REs and FWDs etc from subject line

        var emailmsg = messages[lastmsg].getBody(); // get html content of last message

        var emaildate   = messages[lastmsg].getDate(); // get DATE field of last message

        var attachments = messages[lastmsg].getAttachments(); // get all attachments of last message

        var edate = Utilities.formatDate(emaildate, "IST", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy"); // get date component from emaildate
        var etime = Utilities.formatDate(emaildate, "IST", "h:mm a"); // get time component from emaildate

    if (emailFrom.length == 0)
        {
          // if emailFrom is empty, it probably means that you may have written the last message in the thread. Hence 'you'.
          var emailheader = '<html><body>' + 
                            'On' + '&nbsp;' +
                             edate + '&nbsp;' + 
                            'at' + '&nbsp;' + 
                             etime +  ',' + '&nbsp;' + 'you' + '&nbsp;' + 'wrote:' + '</body></html>';
        } else 
        {
          var emailheader = '<html><body>' + 
                            'On' + '&nbsp;' +
                             edate + '&nbsp;' + 
                            'at' + '&nbsp;' + 
                             etime +  ',' + '&nbsp;' + emailFrom + '&nbsp;' + 'wrote:' + '</body></html>';
        }
          var emailsig = '<html>' + 
                         '<div>your email signature,</div>' +
                         '</html>'; // your email signature i.e. common for all emails.

                  // Build the email message
          var emailBody =  '<p>Hi ' + firstName + ',<p>';
              emailBody += '<p>For ' + subjectCol + ', you will be graded on #1, 2, and 3: <p>';
              emailBody += '<p>Participation: ' + pgrade + '</p>';
              emailBody += '<p>HW grade: ' + hgrade + '</p>';
              emailBody += '<p>If you have any questions, you can email me at ' + grader + '@email.com.<p>';
              emailBody += '<p>- ' + grader;


          var draftmsg = emailBody + '<br>' + emailsig + '<br>' + emailheader + '<br>' + emailmsg + '\n'; // message content of draft

      // Create the email draft
      messages[lastmsg].createDraftReply(
        " ", // Body (plain text)
        {
        htmlBody: emailBody    // Options: Body (HTML)
        }
      );

    }

}
}

function WebSafe(fullstring)
{
  var splitString = fullstring.split(",");
  var finalarray = [];
  for (u=0; u < splitString.length; u++)
  {
    var start_pos = splitString[u].indexOf("<") + 1;
    var end_pos   = splitString[u].indexOf(">",start_pos);
    if (!(splitString[u].indexOf("<") === -1 && splitString[u].indexOf(">",start_pos) === -1)) // if < and > do exist in string
    {
      finalarray.push(splitString[u].substring(start_pos, end_pos));
    } else if (!(splitString[u].indexOf("@") === -1))
    {
      finalarray.push(splitString[u]);
    }
  }
  var index = finalarray.indexOf(grader + "@email.com"); // use your email id. if the array contains your email id, it is removed.
  if (index > -1) {finalarray.splice(index, 1);}
  return finalarray
}
}
```

I've never coded in JavaScript before or used Google Scripts so I mostly looked at similar examples.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your current issue of your script from your question. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: Of course! So my situation is that I regularly receive homework submissions for each student and record their grades on a Google Sheet. Afterwards, I reply to each email with the information from the Google Sheet. This is really tedious since I have to email each student for each homework assignment I received according to the data on the Sheet. Each row starting at row 3 represents a student and columns A-C are information that I include in the email draft.

Comment: I've managed to set up the code to automatically draft the email with a template including that information but I'm struggling to have it iterate though each homework assignment starting with column D. I hope to be able to get the code to automatically draft a reply to each emails containing the unique Subject # instead of just their most recent email (which is what I have the code set for so far). I'm not sure yet how to filter for specific emails having the keyword in the subject line.

Comment: Another issue is having setting the loop to prepare a drafted reply for each row/student for each received email with the subject line in column D and so on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current issue from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your current issue and your goal, I would like to think of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer reading code that isn't too nested. So I took the liberty to re-write your code and make it easier to read.

#### Your main function:

```js
function mainFunction(){

  // Use data from the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('<YOUR-LABEL-HERE>').getThreads();
  var subject1 = data[1][3];

  // Work through each row in the spreadsheet omit headers
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; ++i) {

    // Get grader's data
    var grader = getGrader(data[i]);
    console.log(grader);

    // Loop through threads
    for (j=0; j < threads.length; j++){
      var thread = threads[j];
      // Get last message in thread
      var messages = thread.getMessages(); 
      var lastMsg = messages[messages.length - 1];
      var email = new Email(grader, lastMsg, subject1);
      // Create the draft reply.
      var draftMessageBody = createDraftMessage(email);
      lastMsg.createDraftReply(draftMessageBody);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Support functions:

1. Function **`getGrader`**:

```js
function getGrader(array){ 
  var row = array
  var grader = {}
  grader.grader = row[0];                    
  grader.firstName = row[1];                 
  grader.studentEmail = row[2];              
  var grade = row[3].split(' ');          
  grader.pgrade = grade[1];
  grader.hgrade = grade[0];
  return grader
}
```

2. Function **`webSafe`**:

```js
function webSafe(fullstring, grader){
  var splitString = fullstring.split(",");
  var finalarray = [];
  for (u=0; u < splitString.length; u++){
    var start_pos = splitString[u].indexOf("<") + 1;
    var end_pos   = splitString[u].indexOf(">",start_pos);
    // if < and > do exist in string
    if (!(splitString[u].indexOf("<") === -1 && splitString[u].indexOf(">",start_pos) === -1)){
      finalarray.push(splitString[u].substring(start_pos, end_pos));
    } else if (!(splitString[u].indexOf("@") === -1)){
      finalarray.push(splitString[u]);
    }
  }
  // use your email id. if the array contains your email id, it is removed.
  var index = finalarray.indexOf(grader.grader + "@mangoroot.com"); 
  if (index > -1) {
    finalarray.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return finalarray
}
```

3. Function **`Email`**: *Behaves like a class*

```js
var Email = function(grader, lastMsg, subject){
  this.signature = "your_email_signature,";
  this.grader = grader;
  this.to = webSafe(lastMsg.getTo(), this.grader);
  this.from = webSafe(lastMsg.getFrom(), this.grader);
  this.cc = webSafe(lastMsg.getCc(), this.grader);
  this.subject = lastMsg.getSubject().replace(/([\[\(] *)?(RE|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$/igm,"");
  this.message = lastMsg.getBody();
  this.date = lastMsg.getDate();
  this.attachments = lastMsg.getAttachments();
  this.subject1 = subject;

  this.ccHeader = function() {
    var ccHeader = "";
    if (this.to == "" || this.cc == ""){
      ccHeader = this.cc.toString();
    }
    else {
      ccHeader = this.to.toString() + "," + this.cc.toString();
    }
    return ccHeader
  }

  this.eDate = function() {
    return Utilities.formatDate(this.date, "IST", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy");
  }

  this.eTime = function() {
    return Utilities.formatDate(this.date, "IST", "h:mm a");
  }

  this.header = function() {
    var header = ''.concat('On ');
    if (this.from.length == 0){
      header += this.eDate().concat(' at ',this.eTime(),', you wrote: ');
    }
    else {
      header += this.eDate().concat(' at ',this.eTime(),', ',this.from,' wrote: ');
    }
    return header
  }

  this.body = function(){
    var grader = this.grader;
    var body =  '<div>'.concat('<p>Hi ',grader.firstName,',</p>');
    body += '<p>For '.concat(this.subject1,', you will be graded on #1, 2, and 3: </p>');
    body += '<p>Participation: '.concat(grader.pgrade,'</p>');
    body += '<p>HW grade: '.concat(grader.hgrade,'</p>');
    body += '<p>If you have any questions, you can email me at '.concat(grader.grader,'@mangoroot.com.</p>');
    body += '<p>- '.concat(grader.grader,'</p>','</div>');
    return body;
  }
}
```

4. Function **`createDraftMessage`**:

```js
function createDraftMessage(email){
  var draft = '<html><body>'.concat(email.body);
  draft += '<br>'.concat(email.signature);
  draft += '<br>'.concat(email.header);
  draft += '<br>'.concat(email.message);
  draft += '<br>'.concat('</body></html>');
  return draft;
}
```

---

### Now when you run `mainFunction()` you should get your expected drafts.

---

**Notes:**

- It is good practice to keep functions flat, flat is better than nested. Makes the code more readable and maintainable.
- Also be consistent in your variable naming style.

```js
var emailMsg = ''; // Good. 
var emailmsg = ''; // Hard to read.
```

- Have a read about [`classes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)